# How to show and hide a window in JavaFX 2?

Tags: javafx-2, hidden-files

Need to show an example in which you show and hide a window in JavaFX 2.

Answer (score 2):

A `stage` is a window in javafx-2. It provide the [hide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#hide%28%29) and [show](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show%28%29) methods:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HideShowApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setX(10);
        Scene innerScene = new Scene(new Label("inner window"));
        window.setScene(innerScene);

        HBox root = new HBox(10d);
        Button showButton = new Button("show");
        showButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                window.show();
            }
        });
        Button hideButton = new Button("hide");
        hideButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                window.hide();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(showButton);
        root.getChildren().add(hideButton);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to completely hide window?

Comment: A stage is a window in JavaFX but take note in the API that the `hide()` function of a stage in JavaFX is equivalent to the `close()` function