# Is there a difference between hiding and closing a stage in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2

And how can I show a hidden stage in JavaFX again if there is no difference ?

I open a new window by pressing a button. When I close the new window, it should not be closed, but only hide so that I can display it again (If I click the same button again). It should saved the settings of the window. (For example, position of the window or text that I have entered in text fields). Is this somehow possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaFX, but my wild guess is yes. Closing should delete the object hold in the heap. Therefore for your purpose hiding is better.

Comment: FYI, your question has already been asked @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520573/how-to-show-and-hide-a-window-in-javafx-2. 
A useful tip : -> Try to search before asking.

Comment: There's no difference. But what happens if you call show() on a hidden window? Doesn't it show again?

Comment: No, it does not show again, once it is hidden or closed :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the close method will call the hide method internally.