# JavaFX+MVC. How to hide/show multiple windows?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

How to make that when i click on "Open second window" the main window be hide. And when i close second window, the main window be showed? I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520573/how-to-show-and-hide-a-window-in-javafx-2), but i don't know how to implement it for my task. Thanks!

I have next code:
**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("First Stage");
        try {
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MainWiew.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane id="rootMain" prefHeight="418.0" prefWidth="691.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.view.MainController">
   <top>

   </top>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <VBox fillWidth="false" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="394.0" spacing="8.0">
               <children>
                  <Button id="btnMainOne" fx:id="btnMainOne" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="398.0" text="Open second window" textFill="#4460ff">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>

               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**MainController.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Button btnMainOne;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        btnMainOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                try {
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.setTitle("Second stage");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
                    stage.show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the primary window by calling `getScene().getWindow()`. You can call `hide()` on it to hide it after you show the new stage, and you can register an event listener with the new stage that shows the primary window when the new stage is hidden:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    btnMainOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            Stage primaryStage = (Stage)btnMainOne.getScene().getWindow();

            try {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Second stage");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));

                stage.setOnHidden(e -> primaryStage.show());

                stage.show();

                primaryStage.hide();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

}
```